# rsync unexplained error (code 129)

Tags: rsync

I am trying to rsync the data from one server to another, and approximately ~1.1T of data, but when am doing rsync I am getting following exception in the middle of transfer terminating the process.

rsync error: unexplained error (code 129) at rsync.c(541) [sender=3.0.7]

nohup rsync -r -t -v -o -g -p  -c -l -z /source/images/ranker root@xx.xxxx.xxx.xx:/mnt/source/images &

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/42070212/2908724