# broken pipe with remote rsync between two servers

Tags: linux, bash, rsync, scp

I am trying to transfer a large dataset (768 Gigs) from one remote machine to another using bash on ubuntu 16.04. The problem I appear to be having is that I use rsync and the machine will transfer for a few hours and then quit when the connection inevitably gets interrupted. So suppose Im on machine A and the remote servers are machines B and C (all machines using ubuntu 16.04). I ssh to machine B and use this command:

```
nohup rsync -P -r -e ssh /path/to/files/on/machine_B user@machine_C:directory &
```

note that I have the authorized key setup so no password is required between machines B and C

A few hours later I get the following in the nohup file:

```
sending incremental filelist
file_1.bam
90,310,583,648 100%   36.44MB/s    0:39:23 (xfr#4, to-chk=5/10)
file_2.bam
79,976,321,885 100%   93.25MB/s    0:13:37 (xfr#3, to-chk=6/10)
file_3.bam
88,958,959,616  88%   12.50MB/s    0:15:28  rsync error: unexplained error (code 129) at rsync.c(632) [sender=3.1.1]
rsync: [sender] write error: Broken pipe (32)
```

I used nohup because I though it would keep running even if there was a hangup. I have not tried sh -c and I have not tried running the command from machine A because at this point whatever I try would be guesswork, ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/15209794/2908724

Comment: On machine B, `echo $TMOUT`.

Comment: Thank you, I can remove my question since it appears to duplicate the question you linked; however, I think mine contains a little more explanation. I did not know about the $TMOUT variable - it does not appear to be set on machine B. Is there a way to set it for say 48 hours, perhaps this would help.

Comment: I would not delete your question, for the reason you mentioned. I just made a note here of another unanswered, identical question, so that if one gets an answer, the other will, too. As for setting `TMOUT`, if it's currently unset that means bash should give your ssh an unlimited shell login.

Comment: Try adding `-vvv` to your `rsync` command line, as well.

Comment: Also, while rsync is running, keep an eye on memory with `free` (or htop, etc) on machine B.

Comment: And also, you might want to try `tar -cf - /path/to/files/on/machineB | ssh machineC tar -xf- -c directory` instead.

Answer (score 0):

for those that are interested I also tried running the following script with the nohup command on machine B.

script:

```
chomp( my @files = `ls /path/to/files/on/machineB/*` );
foreach ( @files ) { system("scp $_ user@machineC:destination/"); }
```

I still got truncated files.

at the moment the following command appears to be working:

```
nohup rsync -P --append -r -e ssh /path/to/files/on/machine_B user@machine_C:directory &
```

you just have to check the nohup file for a broken pipe error and re-enter the command if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it in multiple steps:

1. First I made sure that I ran all commands on tmux terminals. This adds a layer of safety on top of nohup, as it keeps connections alive: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux
2. I combined the rsync command with the while command to enforce that the copy is attempted an infinite number of times even if the pipe breaks:

```
while ! rsync <your_source> <your_destination>; do echo "Rsync failed. Retrying ..."; done
```

This approach is brute force and it will work if for each attempt, rsync manages to copy at least a few files. Eventually, even with wasteful repeats and multiple failures, all the files will be copied and my command above will exit gratefully.